# Select the first 5 rows and get count

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to write a mysql query:
first select 5 rows and then get count with a where

first select 5 rows
table

```
id user_id
--------
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  1
5  1
6  4
7  3
8  1

id user_id
----------
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  1
5  1
```

And then get count this table where user_id =1

result = 3

Comment: when you know that you are selecting 5 rows then why you need count ?

Comment: You need to supply more info man, infoman.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you ask a question, it's best to be specific as possible. Answering your question as you asked it takes a lot of guesswork, and we are volunteers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try somthing like that

```
Select count(*) From
(Select * From T
order by ID asc Limit 5) as child
where user_id = 1
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that putting `Top 5` after the from clause is not valid syntax in MySQL (Or any other DBMS I know of), `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T WHERE User_id = 1` can only ever return 1 row anyway, so limiting it to 5 rows is pointless.

Comment: u are right have changed the position of the "top", it could be more than 1 if user_id is not a prime key

Comment: In SQL Server it's TOP(5).  In Oracle it's some complex monkey business involving a ROWNUM synthetic field. In MySQL, it's LIMIT 5.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Join

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to present two different result sets together. You need to use a JOIN for this.  Something like so will do the trick for you.

```
SELECT T.*,c.cnt
  FROM T
  JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM T where user_id = 1 ) c
 LIMIT 5
```

The subquery generates your count as a one-row resultset, and the JOIN (which lacks an ON condition) puts it into every row of your other resultset.

If you wanted to show five rows from your table, and have each row mention the count for the userid in that row, you could do this.

```
SELECT T.*,c.cnt
  FROM T
  JOIN (  SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, user_id
            FROM T 
           GROUP BY user_id
       ) c ON T.user_id = c.user_id
 LIMIT 5
```

The way that summary (COUNT(), etc) queries and detail queries work together is a little intricate, but you will figure it out.

Beware, though:  If you do a LIMIT without first doing an ORDER BY, MySQL is free to return any five rows it pleases.

Comment: Why with the first code I get all count from table where user_id = 1?

Comment: That's what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Note that in the absence of an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT is fairly meaningless.